# How do I compare an enum with its zeroth value?

Tags: c, enums

In c, it is not defined by the standard whether enums are signed or unsigned. However, when I try to compare an enum value to the lowest (ie 0) enumeration constant, I get the warning "pointless comparison of unsigned integer with zero." (Compiler is IAR embedded workbench.)

```
typedef enum
{
    BAR,
    BAZ
} Foo;

//later...
Foo x = (Foo)some_integral_value;
if (x >= BAR) // <- this gives me the warning
    //stuff
```

I need to check the range of the enum, however, because it is being converted from an integral type. Is there a good way to do this that avoids the warning, which will still work if the compiler decides to change the underlying type?

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or **include a minimal example in the question itself.**"

Comment: @abelenky which information are you missing here?

Comment: If an enum is unsigned, then the statement `if ( value >= 0 )` will always be true since an unsigned number is always >= 0.

Comment: Which comparison is he using? `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, or `!=`?  Actual Code answers almost all questions.

Comment: @user3386109 that is true, however an enum is not necessarily unsigned.

Comment: @abelenky Example added.

Comment: @abelenky oh. that's true. But then you could have provided more information in your comment as well ;-).

Comment: @Dan If `some_integral_value` is a signed number, you should check that `some_integral_value` is >= 0 before casting it.  If `some_integral_value` is unsigned, then there's nothing to check. There's still the problem that the cast may not result in a valid enum value, which is to say that casting random integral values to an enum is bad practice.

Comment: @user3386109 I think I'll do that, it seems to make the most sense.

Comment: Maybe `#if BAR != 0 if (x >= BAR)  #endif do_stuff();`?

Comment: @chux Not enough. `BAR` may still be 0 while others are < 0.

Comment: @glglgl I see.  It works here as `BAR` is apparently unsigned.  But it fails in the general case as when `BAR` is signed.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 2):

In C this is a false problem.

- all enumeration *constants* are always of type `int`, anyhow
- conversions back and forth the enumeration *type* work easily with
  implicit conversion, no explicit conversions (AKA cast) are necessary
  nor desirable

Now to your example

```
enum Foo
{
    BAR,
    BAZ
};

//later...
Foo x = (Foo)some_integral_value;
```

This doesn't even compile, because in C `Foo` is not defined to be anything, you must use `enum Foo`, or provide an appropriate `typedef`, something like

```
typedef enum Foo Foo;
```

Perhaps you compile C code with a C++ compiler? In any case, provide a complete example that shows your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like in C, all enums should have type `int`, but I'm leaving these suggestions around, since your compiler is either non-standard C, or compiling as C++.

---

If you have control over the definitions of these enums, you could just make them start at 1:

```
enum Foo
{
    BAR = 1,
    BAZ
};
```

---

You could also add a single fake negative value to force it to be signed:

```
enum Foo
{
    NEGATIVE_PLACEHOLDER = -1,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
};
```

---

In C++11, you can give your enum an explicit underlying type:

```
enum Foo : int
{
    BAR,
    BAZ
};
```

See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), specifically the section that says:

> `enum name : type { enumerator = constexpr , enumerator = constexpr , ... }`
>
> ...
>
> 2) declares an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed

It sounds like the type should always be predictable though:

> Values of unscoped enumeration type are implicitly-convertible to integral types. If the underlying type is not fixed, the value is convertible first type from the following list able to hold their entire value range: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, or `unsigned long long`. If the underlying type is fixed, the values can be converted to their promoted underlying type.

So, if your enum fits in an `int`, it should always use an `int`.

Comment: -1, your answer is completely off track: it answers the question for C++ (where it might be correct), but the question is tagged C. There the situation is completely different.

Comment: @JensGustedt No longer by now.

Comment: @glglgl, still not very helpful for C.